# is += not calling didSet, but explicit + does call it, a bug?

Tags: swiftui, combine

i have this code, and if i set my published variable with +=, didSet will not be called. An explicit addition works, is this a bug or intended?

```
import SwiftUI

class Model : ObservableObject {

    @Published var counter : Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("did set called")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var model : Model

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(model.counter)")
            Button(action: {
                print("before")
                self.model.counter += 1
                print("after")
            }) {
                Text("Add +=")
            }
            Button(action: {
                print("before")
                self.model.counter = self.model.counter + 1
                print("after explicit +")
            }) {
                Text("Add")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(Model())
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: On *why* questions, really, only Apple can answer definitely. ;)

Comment: ok, bad question . is it a bug? i corrected my question ;)

Comment: Not bad, just more appropriate, say, for forums.developer.apple.com. I have doubts there is anybody here from Apple. IMO, not a bug.

Comment: As a work around you could use $counter.sink and do your custom logic there. $counter is a publisher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression that was introduced in Xcode 11.4. I noticed it with `.toggle()` on booleans but sounds like the same issue:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class Observable: ObservableObject {
    var standard = false {
        didSet {
            print("Standard didSet")
        }
    }
    @Published var published = false {
        didSet {
            print("Published didSet")
        }
    }
}

let observable = Observable()
observable.standard.toggle() //didSet fires
observable.published.toggle() //didSet does not fire in 11.4 but does in 11.3.1
observable.published = !observable.published //didSet fires
```

Fortunately, as you've discovered, the immediate fix is to just assign to the property explicitly but I hope Apple fixes it. I've filed it as a big in Feedback Assistant. I'll try to remember to update here if I hear anything back.